# How to display data from a particular column across all row and loop it on a <p> tag?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I want to display data from all rows only for the column named 'text_notes' from my db.
And I want to loop that data in a p tag so that all data from column text_notes is displayed one by one till the end.

Below is the code I tried but it displays all the columns of the latest row and doesn't display the other rows.

I want the data from column 'text_notes' from all the rows to be displayed from latest at the bottom to the oldest at the top.

```
<?php
          $query = "SELECT * FROM notes";
          $conn = new mysqli(DBROOT,DBUSER,DBPASS);
          $conn->select_db(DBNAME);

          if ($conn == TRUE) {

          $runQuery = $conn->query($query);
          $resultNum = $runQuery->num_rows;
          $result = $runQuery->fetch_array();
          $resultRow = mysqli_fetch_row($runQuery);
          $notes = $result['text_notes'];


          for ($i = 0; $i < $resultNum;) {

            echo "<p>".$resultRow[$i]."</p>";

            $i++;

          }

          }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DBROOT, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
$query = "SELECT text_notes FROM notes";
$result = $mysqli->query($query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
// Cycle through the result set

$counter = 0;
while(list($text_notes) = $result->fetch_row())

      echo "<p>";
      $counter++;
      echo $counter . " : "; 
      echo " $text_notes  </p>";

// Free the result set

$result->free();
```

I think it works :) Thanks

Comment: Thanks.. It Works .. And what to do If I want to add a serial number like 1. Saved Text, 2. Saved text

Comment: Umhu .. Now its not displaying anything even the results

Comment: It just display 7 and nothing else not even the stored text. I have 7 entries in the db.

Comment: This is last time :p ? Actually i m not testing i m just writing code in this textarea so spelling mistakes :p